# Showing $L_j=-i\hbar~\varepsilon_{jk\ell} x_k\partial_\ell,$ is hermitian by integration by parts

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Using the definition of hermitian operator $A$: $$\int \psi^*(A\phi)dV=\int(A\psi)^*\phi dV,$$ together with the orbital angular momentum $$L_j=~\varepsilon_{jk\ell}x_k p_\ell=-i\hbar~\varepsilon_{jk\ell} x_k\partial_\ell,$$ to show that $L_j$ is hermitian. Here, I've used Einstein's summation convention for repeated indices.

Now, I am stuck at integration by parts. The LHS is
$$-i\hbar\varepsilon_{jk\ell}\int\psi^*x_k(\partial_\ell\phi)dV\\
=-i\hbar\varepsilon_{jk\ell}\psi^*x_k\int (\partial_\ell\phi)dV +i\hbar\varepsilon_{jk\ell}\int\left[ \partial_\ell(\psi^*x_k)\int (\partial_\ell\phi)dV\right]dV\\
=-i\hbar\varepsilon_{jk\ell}\psi^*x_k\int (\partial_\ell\phi)dV +i\hbar\varepsilon_{jk\ell}\int\left[ \{(\partial_\ell\psi^*)x_k+\psi^*\delta_{k\ell}\}\int (\partial_\ell\phi)dV\right]dV\\
=-i\hbar\varepsilon_{jk\ell}\psi^*x_k\int (\partial_\ell\phi)dV +i\hbar\varepsilon_{jk\ell}\int\left[(\partial_\ell\psi^*)x_k\int (\partial_\ell\phi)dV\right]dV
$$
where I have difficulty writing the next step. Am I doing it right? Any hint on how to proceed after this?

Comment: What are you doing on your first step? Why are you pulling out $\psi^*$?

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo If we don't pull out $\psi^*$, we get, $LHS=-i\hbar\varepsilon_{jk\ell}x_k\int\psi^*\partial_\ell\phi dV$ after integration by parts and noting that we have a term involving $\varepsilon_{jk\ell}$ and $\delta_{k\ell}$ which vanishes. I think we need one more integration by parts. Then how to tackle $\int \partial_\ell\phi dV$?

Answer (score 2):

In your calculation, I sadly cant see how you can pull out some things out of the integral, but here is a solution:
\begin{align}
\int \psi_j^* L_j \phi_j dV&=\int \psi_j^* (-i \epsilon_{jkl}x_k  \partial_l\phi_j)dV \\&=\int -i \epsilon_{jkl} x_k  \psi_j^* \partial_l \phi_j dV \\
& =-\int \epsilon_{jkl} \partial_l (-ix_k \psi_j^*) \phi_j dV \\
&=-\int \epsilon_{jkl}(-i \delta_{kl}\psi_j^*-ix_k \partial_l \psi_j^*)\phi_j dV \\
&=-\int (-i \underbrace{\epsilon_{jkl} \delta_{kl}}_{=0}\psi_j^*-i \epsilon_{jkl} x_k \partial_l \psi^*)\phi_j dV \\
&=-\int (-i\epsilon_{jkl}x_k \partial_l \psi^*_j)\phi_j dV \\
&=\int (-i\epsilon_{jkl}x_k \partial_l \psi_j)^* \phi_j dV \\
&=\int (L_j \psi_j)^* \phi_j dV
\end{align}
Hope I didnt mess up any index, I assumed that all boundary terms vanish, which is a reasonable assumption for dense domains in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Comment: I set $\hbar=1$, so I am working in "natural units" :-)

Comment: Thanks. "I sadly can't see how you can pull some things out of the integral" Well I took $u=\psi^* x_j$ and $v=\partial_\ell\phi$. Why is that wrong?

Comment: Also I think the index $j$ on $\phi,\psi$ are not necessary.

Comment: I'm confused how you got the third line. Can you write the boundary terms? I am lost there.

Comment: Answering your questions 1-by-1:   

1)Yes, it is wrong. Assuming you mean $dV=dx_1 dx_2 dx_3$, $\psi^* x_j$ depends on $x$ and therefore can't be pulled out of the integral.    

2)You can integrate componentwise or take the integral in each vector component for functions from $\Psi, \Phi: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. I added the index to follow "the summation over double indices " convention.

Comment: 3)There are no boundary terms for  reasonable assumptions on $\phi,\psi$ - see any post on integration by parts on $\mathbb{R}^n$, like... [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086433/integration-by-parts-in-mathbbrn). It also works for Schwartz functions. Nevertheless, from a geometrical perspective, you have $\partial \mathbb{R}^3= \emptyset$ and in the light of Stokes' theorem, there shouldn't be any boundary terms anyway.